# How to query for records less than 48 hours in Postgres using knex.js and objection.js?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, knex.js, objection.js

I'd like to query for all records less than 48 hours of age using a `created_at` column.

In PostgreSQL you can do something like:

`SELECT * from "media" WHERE updated_at >= now() - '48 hour'::INTERVAL;`

How do we write this in objection.js/knex.js without going into raw query (or maybe using some raw for part of the equality)?

I have working logic:

```
const { raw } = require('objection');

return SomeModel.query()
  .andWhere(raw('updated_at >= now() - \'48 HOUR\'::INTERVAL'))
  .orderBy('updated_at')
  .first();
```

But I would like to avoid using the `raw` function if possible so something like:

```
return SomeModel.query()
  .where('updated_at', '>=', 'i have no idea what to put here')
  .orderBy('updated_at')
  .first();
```

Upon first thought, since `updated_at` is an `new Date().toISOString()` I may be able to do something along the lines of `< new Date(new Date().getTime()-48*60*60*1000).toISOString()`

But I'm not entirely sure how the Postgres comparator is going to handle this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
const { raw } = require('objection');

SomeModel.query()
  .where('updated_at', '>=', raw(`now() - (?*'1 HOUR'::INTERVAL)`, [48]))
  .orderBy('updated_at')
  .first();
```

Also wrote example in a way that number of hour can be passed as value binding. If value does not have to be changed then using constant `now() - '48 HOUR'::INTERVAL` is fine too.

Comment: Hm. I guess no matter what we'll end up using something with `raw(..)`.

Comment: You will need raw every now and then with knex/objection and there is nothing bad in using it.

Comment: Just for furthering my knowledge, it is possible to do `?*'1 MINUTE` as well?

Comment: @PGT yes you can